# How do I make a Query Based DL for Office 365 users?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, distribution-lists

I am migrating users to Office 365 and have some QBDLs for access control that reference on premise Exchange Servers.

What is the correct way to reference a migrated account in a Query Based DL?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways I can think of.

1. If you are in a Hybrid setup - you can leave these groups in Exchange (they don't migrate anyway) then in O365 create a contact object for the group address.  This will allow O365 users to send messages to these lists.
2. You can recreate your lists in Office 365.  They are now called Dynamic Distribution lists. When you recreate them in O365.  You may need to sync some customer attributes to get the filters you need.